# Django Static Root 404 Error

Tags: python, django, static, django-staticfiles

Right now I am trying to connect my django project html files to static files but keep getting 404 errors. My Project is organized as

```
src
    admin
    homePage
    media
    static 
       homepage
           css
           images
           fonts
           js
    templates
```

in my settings file i have

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'myProjectName/static'),
)
```

and in my html file

```
{% static "home/css/bootstrap.css"%}
```

Why do I keep getting 404 errors ? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Have you included `{% load staticfiles %}` in your template? There is also a discrepancy in your filepath - your filepath states `home`, but your file structure has a folder called `homepage`

Comment: i never included this. where should I place {% load staticfiles %} in my html file ?

Comment: You generally put it at the top, together with any `{% extends "base.html" %}` statements

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Debug=True in your settings file and the error page will help you to find out the issue.