# 404 errors on static assets in Django/Vue app

Tags: python, django, heroku, vue.js

I was trying to follow [this article](https://medium.com/@williamgnlee/simple-integrated-django-vue-js-web-application-configured-for-heroku-deployment-c4bd2b37aa70) to deploy a Django/Vue app to heroku. The steps outlined are to:

- run npm build to create the /dist directory with built files
- to the `TEMPLATES = [...]` section of settings.py, add `'DIRS':[os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist')],`
- add `STATICFILES_DIRS = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist/static')],` (also in settings.py)
- edit the django urls.py file to include this line: `url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),`

I've done all of those things at this point, here is my sanitized settings.py file:

```
"""
Django settings for bad_fortune_cookie project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 2.1.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import dj_database_url
#from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
from rest_framework import *

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '.herokuapp.com','localhost']

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'bad_fortune_cookie',
    #'fortunes'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'bad_fortune_cookie.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'bad_fortune_cookie.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#databases



# Pagination

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'dist/static')
]
```

But I'm still getting 404s on my new files, even after running collectstatic:

[image]

I looked at a number of seemingly related questions (some more relevant than others) but trying the specific solutions in these two answers did not resolve the issue: 
[Error 404 static files in django 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727193/error-404-static-files-in-django-2-0)

[Django Static Root 404 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35393935/django-static-root-404-error)

Any help is appreciated, and if it is helpful the repo is [here.](http://%20https://github.com/jtkaufman737/bad_fortune_cookie)

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from implementation in [github](https://github.com/gtalarico/django-vue-template/blob/69cf0f0a216cd4145b8ef9f0f01364185bbc48ec/vue.config.js), you need to define asset directory in your project like this(copy pasted from the code):

```
module.exports = {
    outputDir: 'dist',
    assetsDir: 'static',
    // baseUrl: IS_PRODUCTION
    // ? 'http://cdn123.com'
    // : '/',
    // For Production, replace set baseUrl to CDN
    // And set the CDN origin to `yourdomain.com/static`
    // Whitenoise will serve once to CDN which will then cache
    // and distribute
    devServer: {
      proxy: {
        '/api*': {
          // Forward frontend dev server request for /api to django dev server
          target: 'http://localhost:8000/',
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Basically what is happening here is that, your static files are being serverd in root path `/`, but static files should be served in path `/static` (ie: `<your server>/static/js/abc.js`)

Comment: This isn't working for me.
Neither `assetsDir` or `publicPath` seems to affect the build and the request still goes to `/js/about.js` instead of `static/js/about.js`... I even have chunk splitting disabled.

Comment: Unfortunately it is a (very) old answer now, and I am out of scope at the moment. Sorry can’t help you at the moment.